# Logic : How to determine whether these propositions are contradictory ?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

http://postimg.org/image/iips2lwdj/

The question asks to draw a truth table with the values of three propositions (linked), and following this, to "Show that the three propositions are contradictory.. and Explain your answer."

Does this mean to simply highlight that the values differ from one another or am I off the mark completely ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ propositions $\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots,\phi_n$ are said to be **contradictory** when their conjunction is a contradiction, i.e. a logical falsehood:
$\overline{v}\left(\bigwedge_{k=1}^{k=n}\phi_k\right)=F$.

In your case, build the conjunction of your three propositions and check if it is possible for it to be true - if not, the three propositions are contradictory.

Comment: Simple and easy to follow. Thank you very much.